# How can I join a species name with the Catalogue of Life Database (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, string-matching

I am trying to cope with the Catalogue of Life database (http://www.catalogueoflife.org/services/index.html) in MySQL. This database contains information on the scientific names of species, both the valid accepted names and invalid or out-of-date synonyms. This (http://www.catalogueoflife.org/services/Database_documentation.pdf) is a PDF explaining how the database works and following is the code used to write and fill the tables:

```
CREATE DATABASE icol2011ac;
USE icol2011ac;
--
-- Table structure for table `author_string`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `author_string`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `author_string` (
`id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`string` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Name of author(s), who described the taxon or published the current combination and the year when appropriate.',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `string` (`string`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=79193 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Author citations of taxa and synonyms';
 /*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
--
-- Table structure for table `hybrid`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `hybrid`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `hybrid` (
  `taxon_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `parent_taxon_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'References two (or three) parent taxon ids',
  PRIMARY KEY (`taxon_id`,`parent_taxon_id`),
  KEY `parent_taxon_id` (`parent_taxon_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Links to parent taxa of hybrids';
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
--
-- Table structure for table `reference`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `reference`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `reference` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `authors` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Complete author string',
  `year` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Year(s) of publication',
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Title of the publication',
  `text` text COMMENT 'Additional information pertaining to the publication',
  `uri_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Link to downloadable version',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `authors` (`authors`),
  KEY `year` (`year`),
  KEY `uri_id` (`uri_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=60462 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='References used for taxa, common names and synonyms';
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
--
-- Table structure for table `reference_to_synonym`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `reference_to_synonym`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `reference_to_synonym` (
  `reference_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `synonym_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`reference_id`,`synonym_id`),
  KEY `synonym_id` (`synonym_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Links references to synonyms';
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
--
-- Table structure for table `reference_to_taxon`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `reference_to_taxon`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `reference_to_taxon` (
  `reference_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `taxon_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`reference_id`,`taxon_id`),
  KEY `taxon_id` (`taxon_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Links references to taxa';
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
--
-- Table structure for table `scientific_name_element`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `scientific_name_element`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `scientific_name_element` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name_element` varchar(100) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Basic element of a scientific name; e.g. the epithet argentatus as used in Larus argentatus argenteus',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name_element` (`name_element`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=204459 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Individual elements used to generate a scientific name';
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
--
-- Table structure for table `scientific_name_status`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `scientific_name_status`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `scientific_name_status` (
  `id` tinyint(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name_status` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Name status of a taxon',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name_status` (`name_status`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Predetermined list of name statuses';
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
--
-- Table structure for table `scrutiny`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `scrutiny`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `scrutiny` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `scrutiny_date` date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Most recent date a taxon name was verified; must parse correctly',
  `original_scrutiny_date` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Date as used in the original database; may be incomplete',
  `specialist_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Link to the specialist who examined the validity of a taxon',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique` (`scrutiny_date`,`specialist_id`,`original_scrutiny_date`),
  KEY `scrutiny_date` (`scrutiny_date`),
  KEY `specialist_id` (`specialist_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1271 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Latest scrutiny date of a taxon';
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
--
-- Table structure for table `source_database`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `source_database`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `source_database` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Full name of the source database',
  `abbreviated_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Abbreviated name of the source database',
  `group_name_in_english` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Name in English of the group(s) treated in the database',
  `authors_and_editors` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Optional author(s) and editor(s) of the source database',
  `organisation` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Optional organisation which has compiled or is owning the source database',
  `contact_person` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Optional contact person of the source database',
  `version` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Optional version number of the source database',
  `release_date` date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Optional most recent release date of the source database',
  `abstract` text COMMENT 'Optional free text field describing the source database',
  #`taxonomic_coverage` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`,`abbreviated_name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=79 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Information about source databases';
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
--
-- Table structure for table `specialist`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `specialist`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `specialist` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=182 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Specialists who have verified the validity of taxa';
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
--
-- Table structure for table `synonym`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `synonym`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `synonym` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `taxon_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Link to valid taxon to which the synonym relates',
  `author_string_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Link to author citation of the synonym',
  `scientific_name_status_id` tinyint(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Link to the name status of the synonym',
  `original_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `taxon_id` (`taxon_id`),
  KEY `author_string_id` (`author_string_id`),
  KEY `scientific_name_status_id` (`scientific_name_status_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=7618428 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Synonym details linked to a valid taxon';
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
--
-- Table structure for table `synonym_name_element`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `synonym_name_element`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `synonym_name_element` (
  `taxonomic_rank_id` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `scientific_name_element_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `synonym_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `hybrid_order` tinyint(1) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Order of parents if synonym is a hybrid; see documentation for details',
  UNIQUE KEY `unique` (`taxonomic_rank_id`,`synonym_id`),
  KEY `taxonomic_rank_id` (`taxonomic_rank_id`),
  KEY `scientific_name_element_id` (`scientific_name_element_id`),
  KEY `synonym_id` (`synonym_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Name elements of a complete synonym';
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
--
-- Table structure for table `taxon`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `taxon`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `taxon` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `taxonomic_rank_id` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `source_database_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `original_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `taxonomic_rank_id` (`taxonomic_rank_id`),
  KEY `source_database_id` (`source_database_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=7618427 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Scientific name elements and hierarchy of a taxon';
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
--
-- Table structure for table `taxonomic_coverage`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `taxonomic_coverage`;
CREATE TABLE `taxonomic_coverage` (
  `source_database_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `taxon_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `sector` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  `point_of_attachment` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  KEY `source_database_id` (`source_database_id`),
  KEY `sector` (`sector`),
  KEY `taxon_id` (`taxon_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
--
-- Table structure for table `taxon_detail`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `taxon_detail`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `taxon_detail` (
  `taxon_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `author_string_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Link to author citation of the taxon',
  `scientific_name_status_id` tinyint(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `scrutiny_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `additional_data` text COMMENT 'Optional free text field describing the taxon',
  PRIMARY KEY (`taxon_id`),
  KEY `author_string_id` (`author_string_id`),
  KEY `taxononomic_status_id` (`scientific_name_status_id`),
  KEY `scrutiny_id` (`scrutiny_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Details pertaining to species and infraspecies';
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
--
-- Table structure for table `taxon_name_element`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `taxon_name_element`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `taxon_name_element` (
  `taxon_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `scientific_name_element_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`taxon_id`),
  KEY `scientific_name_element_id` (`scientific_name_element_id`),
  KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
--
-- Table structure for table `taxonomic_rank`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `taxonomic_rank`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `taxonomic_rank` (
  `id` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rank` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Taxonomic rank (e.g. family, subspecies)',
  `marker_displayed` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `standard` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `rank` (`rank`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=132 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Predetermined list of taxonomic ranks';
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2010-12-16 15:47:12

-- Added quick fix for adding non-ISO countries and languages to ISO tables

ALTER TABLE `language` ADD `standard` TINYINT( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1';
ALTER TABLE `country` ADD `standard` TINYINT( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1';
ALTER TABLE `country` CHANGE `iso` `iso` CHAR( 3 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'ISO 3166-1-Alpha-2 code';
ALTER TABLE `common_name` CHANGE `country_iso` `country_iso` CHAR( 3 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Optional country code if usage is restricted to a particular country' ;


#PART2: importing files into MySQL

LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Quasi Eigene Dateien/Catalogue of Life/2011AC_baseschema_dump/author_string.txt' INTO TABLE author_string FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Quasi Eigene Dateien/Catalogue of Life/2011AC_baseschema_dump/hybrid.txt' INTO TABLE hybrid FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Quasi Eigene Dateien/Catalogue of Life/2011AC_baseschema_dump/reference.txt' INTO TABLE reference FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Quasi Eigene Dateien/Catalogue of Life/2011AC_baseschema_dump/reference_to_synonym.txt' INTO TABLE reference_to_synonym FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Quasi Eigene Dateien/Catalogue of Life/2011AC_baseschema_dump/reference_to_taxon.txt' INTO TABLE reference_to_taxon FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Quasi Eigene Dateien/Catalogue of Life/2011AC_baseschema_dump/region.txt' INTO TABLE region FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Quasi Eigene Dateien/Catalogue of Life/2011AC_baseschema_dump/scientific_name_element.txt' INTO TABLE scientific_name_element FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Quasi Eigene Dateien/Catalogue of Life/2011AC_baseschema_dump/scientific_name_status.txt' INTO TABLE scientific_name_status FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Quasi Eigene Dateien/Catalogue of Life/2011AC_baseschema_dump/scrutiny.txt' INTO TABLE scrutiny FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Quasi Eigene Dateien/Catalogue of Life/2011AC_baseschema_dump/source_database.txt' INTO TABLE source_database FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Quasi Eigene Dateien/Catalogue of Life/2011AC_baseschema_dump/specialist.txt' INTO TABLE specialist FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Quasi Eigene Dateien/Catalogue of Life/2011AC_baseschema_dump/synonym.txt' INTO TABLE synonym FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Quasi Eigene Dateien/Catalogue of Life/2011AC_baseschema_dump/synonym_name_element.txt' INTO TABLE synonym_name_element FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Quasi Eigene Dateien/Catalogue of Life/2011AC_baseschema_dump/taxon.txt' INTO TABLE taxon FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Quasi Eigene Dateien/Catalogue of Life/2011AC_baseschema_dump/taxon_detail.txt' INTO TABLE taxon_detail FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Quasi Eigene Dateien/Catalogue of Life/2011AC_baseschema_dump/taxon_name_element.txt' INTO TABLE taxon_name_element FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Quasi Eigene Dateien/Catalogue of Life/2011AC_baseschema_dump/taxonomic_rank.txt' INTO TABLE taxonomic_rank FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

I furthermore have a long table of museum specimens containing scientific names (both valid and invalid names) that I need to check against the Catalogue of Life database. So, for each name in my table I need to check whether it is a valid name, and if it instead is an invalid synonym, assign the currently valid name to it.

The names in my museum specimen table have the following format:
          genus       species epithet         subspecies epithet      author/year
e.g..     *Bellis*    *perennis*              -                       L.
Each line always contains information on the genus and the species, information on subspecies and author/year is not always given.

I find it extremely difficult to think through the necessary query code for this taxonomic matchup as only the combination of up to three elements (genus name element, species name element and sometimes subspecies name element) from the one table, together with information on taxon id, taxonomic rank, and taxon name status from other tables creates the valid names and synonyms.

My museum specimens are stored in one large table, with the genus name, the species name, and sometimes the subspecies name and/or the author each being stored in different columns.

A solution to structure the query code accordingly would be much appreciated !! Thanks a lot already for taking the time go through this !!

Answer (score 0):

I would not try to solve your problem with just MySQL queries - I would use a procedural programming language to write a program that can handle the complexities you describe. Depending on what you (or those around you) are familiar with, you could use perl, python, or even php to write the code.

This application could go through each line of your museum's table, and make a number of attempts per line to match to the Catalog of Life. You might match multiple lines, you might need to disambiguate by adding a subspecies, you might not find anything that matches exactly but perhaps matches partially. Your program would handle each one of these cases in a comprehensive way, giving you the output that was most suitable.